# c fgets stuck in beginning of file

Tags: c

Tried to use the following basic code, but the output file is filled with null charachters in an infinite loop.
After using `ftell` I could see that the `inFile` pointer stuck on the second char and is not proceeding.
Where is my mistake? why is `fgets` get stuck?

```
char line[MAX_LINE];

while ((fgets(line, MAX_LINE, inFile)) != NULL)
{
    int i = 0;
    *(strchr(line, '\n')) = '\0';

    while (line[i] != '\0')
    {
        fprintf(outFile, "%c", line[i]);
        i++;
    }
}
```

Comment: What happens in your code if you don't encounter a new line `\n`, then `strchr` would return a `null` pointer, which you would then dereference and set to `\0`, you should really check the result of `strchr`.

Comment: Why use `fprintf(outFile, "%c", line[i]);` over `fprintf(outFile, "%s", line);`? You already null terminated it at the first newline.

Answer (score 3):

I changed the contents of the line:

```
*(strchr(line, '\n')) = '\0';
```

To

```
char* ptr = strchr(line, '\n');
if (ptr) {
    *ptr = '\0';
}
```

See: https://ideone.com/jQr7ne

And it worked. The problem was, as mentioned in the comments, that you always dereferenced the return value of `strchr` even if the line contained no newline character. In my example the last line didn't. Which made the function `strchr` return `NULL` which in turn caused a runtime error.

While I am at it, I would suggest changing the loop sending the line buffer to the output file from sending a character at a time to sending the entire buffer. Like this:

```
while ((fgets(line, MAX_LINE, inFile)) != NULL)
{
    char* ptr = strchr(line, '\n');
    if (ptr) {
        *ptr = '\0';
    }

    fputs(line, outFile);
}
return 0;
```

This eliminates a loop and a variable that is not required, and has a bit less overhead.